# Append an empty list but got converted to NoneType

Tags: python, list

In the following code:

```
all_subsets = []
subsets = [[], [2]]
left_most = 1 
for subset in subsets:
    print subset
    all_subsets.append(subset)
    all_subsets.append(subset.append(left_most))
print all_subsets
```

I suppose the return should be `[[], [1], [2], [2, 1]]`, but I actually got the return of `[[1], None, [2, 1], None]`. i.e., `[]` has been converted to `None`.

I suppose it's the problem of modifying `subset` in the loop twice, which pointing to the same physical address. However, I can't fix the problem even if I make a local copy before modify the list, such as the  following:

```
all_subsets = []
subsets = [[], [2]]
left_most = 1
for subset in subsets:
    print subset
    subset_orig = list(subset)
    subset_plus = list(subset).append(left_most)
    all_subsets.append(subset_orig)
    all_subsets.append(subset_plus)
print all_subsets
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that [`append()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) modifies the list in-place, **and returns `None`**.

Here is one way to fix the code:

```
all_subsets = []
subsets = [[], [2]]
left_most = 1 
for subset in subsets:
    print subset
    all_subsets.append(subset)
    all_subsets.append(subset + [left_most])
print all_subsets
```

This produces `[[], [1], [2], [2, 1]]` as you expect.

Answer (score 5):

`list.append()` always returns `None`, so

```
all_subsets.append(subset.append(left_most))
```

append `None` to `all_subsets`.  You probably simply want

```
subset.append(left_most)
```

since you already appended `subset` to `all_subsets` in the line before.